# Execute react-native debug code on iPhone without USB and Expo

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, mobile, localhost

I am trying to execute my react-native app on my physical iPhone but I don't have the converter so I can't able to use USB and also when I try to use expo for this reason, it doesn't work, it shows the same message(i.e., slow internet speed) all the time even though the Wi-Fi speed is pretty good.

It would be good if someone provide me a reliable way to achieve the same without using expo and USB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in bare React Native project. You've to use USB one time, then you can switch to work through Wi-Fi. Maybe problem is raised in Expo when you converted in from bare React Native to Expo.